# cs50 Pset5 Speller segmentation fault and memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, cs50

So i have been trying to complete the cs50, Problem Set 5, speller problem and i have done the entire code without any reference except their own walkthrough videos on their website.

i have tried looking at other people's code but there is some problem with my code that I just don't get why it is happening.
the code compiles fine, but gives a segmentation fault.

when i use valgrind then it tells me that there are many leaks and files needed to be closed, but i have already done all those changes wherever needed and compiled my code several times already.

Here's my code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
// LENGTH is a const int = 45
const unsigned int N = LENGTH; 

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Size no.
int size_number = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int n = hash(word);

    for (node *cursor = table[n]; cursor->next != NULL; cursor = cursor->next)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int n = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(word[i]) || word[i] == '\'')
        {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open dictionary\n");
        return false;
    }
    char word[N];

    while(fscanf(dict, "%s", word))
    {
        int n = fscanf(dict, "%s", word);
        if (n == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        size_number++;

        node *loaded_word = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (loaded_word == NULL)
        {
            fclose(dict);
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(loaded_word->word, word);

        int index = hash(loaded_word->word);

        loaded_word->next = table[index];
        table[index]->next = loaded_word;
    }

    fclose(dict);

    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return size_number;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        while(table[i] != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

i used it with

```
valgrind ./speller texts/cat.txt
```

cat.txt is

```
A cat is not a caterpillar.
```

and here's the valgrind output

```
==6031== Invalid write of size 8
==6031==    at 0x401BDE: load (dictionary.c:90)
==6031==    by 0x4012BE: main (speller.c:40)
==6031==  Address 0x30 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6031== 
==6031== 
==6031== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==6031==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x30
==6031==    at 0x401BDE: load (dictionary.c:90)
==6031==    by 0x4012BE: main (speller.c:40)
==6031==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6031==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6031==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6031==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6031==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6031== 
==6031== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6031==     in use at exit: 528 bytes in 2 blocks
==6031==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 4,624 bytes allocated
==6031== 
==6031== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==6031==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6031==    by 0x401B74: load (dictionary.c:79)
==6031==    by 0x4012BE: main (speller.c:40)
==6031== 
==6031== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==6031==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6031==    by 0x4A2592D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==6031==    by 0x4A2592D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==6031==    by 0x401ACE: load (dictionary.c:62)
==6031==    by 0x4012BE: main (speller.c:40)
==6031== 
==6031== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6031==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6031==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6031==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6031==    still reachable: 528 bytes in 2 blocks
==6031==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6031== 
==6031== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==6031== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
/opt/cs50/bin/valgrind: line 11:  6031 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

i have closed the dict file and freed memory wherever i think it was needed, but it still gives me the same output, and i cannot pinpoint the problem or problems in the code. any help is appreciated. :)

EDIT: I forgot to tell about how my hash function works. my hash function sorts the words  according to their length, so how many letters a word has, so 'apple' and 'action' are in different linked lists, but 'action' and 'banana' are in the same. this is why no. of buckets = LENGTH which is the lengthiest word possible for this problem.

Comment: Please work on providing a [mre] in your question. (@xing asking for certain missing details can get very tedious, so please instead of naming specific shortcoming, better ask for a `[mre]`, which is a convenient shortcut for comments like yours and mine).

Comment: You never initialize `table` to point to anything. Change `node *table[N];` --> `node *table;` Then in `main` do: `table = calloc(N, sizeof(*table));`

Comment: Also, for extra safety, in `hash` change `return n;` into `return n % N;`